# Add period (.) to high rate

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Please add a period to the end of the sentence:

> This company responds to the majority of applications it receives

Found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/151709/senior-tech-writer-engineer-govpilot?so=i&sec=False&pg=4&offset=18

As well as found on any job that "responds fast".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After consulting with our design team, we decided to fix this grievous punctuation omission.  Enjoy!
[image]

Comment: Ok dont forget my paycheck.